# How to add an Interface into a constructor in an ItemProcessor with SpringBatch

Tags: java, spring-batch, hexagonal-architecture

In my java project I use the hexagonal architecture.
I have an Interface "Use Case" called RapprochementUseCase who is implemented by a Service called "RapprochementService".

In my ItemProcessor of my spring batch step I need to call to my Interface "RapprochementUseCase", so in my Processor I put in my constructor the interface thank's to the annotation RequiredArgsConstructor. But I got an error when I try to put the Interface into the parameter of my Processor.

I don't see in the documentation how to do this.. Do you have any ideas ?

In my declaration of processor :

```
  @Bean
  public ItemProcessor<PlaqueSousSurveillanceEntity, PlaqueLueEntity> rapprochementProcessor() {
    return new RapprochementProcessor(); <-- Error here
  }
```

RapprochementProcessor :

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RapprochementProcessor implements ItemProcessor<PlaqueSousSurveillanceEntity, PlaqueLueEntity> {

  private final RapprochementUseCase rapprochementUseCase;


  @Override
  public PlaqueLueEntity process(PlaqueSousSurveillanceEntity item) {
    log.trace("Traitement d'une entrée PlaqueSousSurveillanceEntity: {}", item);

    List<PlaqueLue> plaqueLues = this.rapprochementUseCase.findRapprochementByPlaque(item.getPlaque());
    return new PlaqueLueEntity();
  }
}
```

When I tried to put the RapprochementUseCase in the contructor of the BatchConfiguration and if I declare the bean like :

```
  @Bean
  public RapprochementUseCase rapprochementUseCase(RapprochementUseCase rapprochementUseCase) {
    return rapprochementUseCase;
  }
```

I got an error : The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RapprochementProcessor` requires a `RapprochementUseCase`, you should have a constructor generated by `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

You need to declare a bean of type `RapprochementUseCase`, and then pass it to your item processor like follows for example:

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<PlaqueSousSurveillanceEntity, PlaqueLueEntity> rapprochementProcessor(RapprochementUseCase rapprochementUseCase) {
    return new RapprochementProcessor(rapprochementUseCase);
}
```

Comment: When I create a Bean of type RapprochementUseCase like that

 ```  @Bean
  public RapprochementUseCase rapprochementUseCase(RapprochementUseCase rapprochementUseCase) {
    return rapprochementUseCase;
  }``` 

And inject this to my processor when you write it in your comment I got "Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true."

I miss something